# C++ Calculating shipping cost based on weight

Tags: c++, duplicates, control-flow

Part of a program that I'm working on implements a function that takes in the package weight as an argument and calculates the shipping cost based on that weight. The criteria for the cost/lb is as follows:

```
        Package Weight              Cost
        --------------              ----
        25 lbs & under              $5.00 (flat rate)
        26 - 50 lbs                 above rate + 0.10/lb over 25
        50 + lbs                    above rate + 0.07/lb over 50
```

I used an if-if else-if to make the calculations, but feel like its a bit repetitive:

```
const int TIER_2_WEIGHT = 25;
const int TIER_3_WEIGHT = 50;

const float TIER_1_RATE = 5.00;
const float TIER_2_RATE = 0.10;
const float TIER_3_RATE = 0.07;

float shipPriceF;


if(shipWeightF <= TIER_2_WEIGHT)
{
    shipPriceF = TIER_1_RATE;
}
else if(shipWeightF <= TIER_3_WEIGHT)
{
    shipPriceF = ((shipWeightF - TIER_2_WEIGHT) * TIER_2_RATE) +
                   TIER_1_RATE;
}
else
{
    shipPriceF = ((shipWeightF - TIER_3_WEIGHT) * TIER_3_RATE)   +
                 ((TIER_3_WEIGHT - TIER_2_WEIGHT) * TIER_2_RATE) +
                   TIER_1_RATE;
}

return shipPriceF;
```

So, the question is... is this the best way to accomplish this task, or should I be looking for a different solution?

Comment: What you have is immaculate in terms of good practice. There is nothing repetitive as far as your usage of if-else if-else is concerned.

Comment: Furthermore, there is nothing recursive here.

Comment: Assuming these are the only tiers, this looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First at all, you code looks clear and ok as it is.

Of course, you could deduplicate the redundant parts of the formulas by using a cumulative approach:

```
float shipPriceF = TIER_1_RATE; // to be paid anyway

if (shipWeightF > TIER_2_WEIGHT) // add the tier 2 if necessary
{
    shipPriceF += (min(shipWeightF, TIER_3_WEIGHT) - TIER_2_WEIGHT) * TIER_2_RATE;
}
if(shipWeightF > TIER_3_WEIGHT)  // add the tier 3 if really necessary
{
    shipPriceF += (shipWeightF - TIER_3_WEIGHT) * TIER_3_RATE);
}
```

Well, this could even be simplified further:

```
float shipPriceF = TIER_1_RATE 
                     + max(min(shipWeightF,TIER_3_WEIGHT)-TIER_2_WEIGHT,0) * TIER_2_RATE 
                     + max(shipWeightF-TIER_3_WEIGHT,0) * TIER_3_RATE;
```

For 3 scales, it's probably ok with this synthetic formula.  If you want more flexibility however, you could think of iterating throug a vector of rates instead of using constants.  This would allow for a variable number of scales. If you're sure that the formula is always progressive (eg. "above + new unit price for what's exceding") use then the cumulative approach.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back! This is more of what i had in mind but couldn't think it through. Much appreciated!

Comment: While your solutions are simplified, would there be any trade offs for efficiency? The first one uses one less comparative operations then my original, but  the last one you posted uses a few min/maxes.. If the rate progression were to be on a larger scale, would it make a difference?

Comment: You are indeed right, but it depends heavily on the optimizer.  For instance, with GCC 6.2 my [first proposal](https://godbolt.org/g/pPQCgO) is only one asm instruction less than your [original code](https://godbolt.org/g/sbkze7).  And my [ultraslim function](https://godbolt.org/g/x3wxeA) is 4 instructions more.  But the overall execution performance depends not only on number of instructions but as well on the statistical distribution of the weight (requiring more or less jumps).  Therefore, my adivce:  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot of nearly identical lines in the code but not real duplicates. If you add more rates you can easily copy the wrong macro definitions or mix the values from the wrong rate.

My code itself removes the if/else replications and avoid the need of using the correct global definition. If you add a new rate to my code you simply add a raw to the table.

Only to give an idea what else can be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <limits>

// first we define a entry of a table. This table contains the limit to which the ratio is valid and
// a function which calculates the price for that part of the weight.
struct RateTableEntry
{
    double max;
    std::function<double(double, double)> func;
};

// only to shrink the table width :-)
constexpr double MAX = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

// and we define a table with the limits and the functions which calculates the price
RateTableEntry table[]=
{
    // first is flate rate up to 25
    {   25, [](double    , double       )->double{ double ret=                      5.00; return ret; }},
    // next we have up to 50 the rate of 0.10 ( use min to get only the weight up to next limit
    {   50, [](double max, double weight)->double{ double ret= std::min(weight,max)*0.10; return ret; }},
    // the same for next ratio. std::min not used, bedause it is the last entry
    {  MAX, [](double    , double weight)->double{ double ret=          weight     *0.07; return ret; }}
};

double CalcRate(double weight)
{
    std::cout << "Price for " << weight;
    double price = 0;
    double offset = 0;
    for ( auto& step: table )
    {
        // call each step, until there is no weight which must be calculated
        price+=step.func(step.max- offset, weight);
        // reduce the weight for that amount which allready is charged for
        weight-=step.max-offset;
        // make the table more readable, if not used this way, we have no max values but amount per step value
        offset+=step.max;
        if ( weight <= 0 ) break;   // stop if all the weight was paid for
    }

    std::cout << " is " << price << std::endl;

    return price;
}

int main()
{
    CalcRate( 10 );
    CalcRate( 26 );
    CalcRate( 50 );
    CalcRate( 51 );
    CalcRate( 52 );
    CalcRate( 53 );
}
```

If C++11 is not available, you also can use normal functions and function pointers instead of lambdas and std::function.